# How to get gmail-create account-password field ToolTip information using web driver selenium

Tags: tooltip, onmouseover

I am trying to get text box Tool tip (Gmail-Create Account-Password field) information but I am failing to handle this situation.

I am using Selenium WebDriver (java). Please find  below code what I have used:

```
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
wd.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Ftab%3Dwm&hl=en");
WebElement NewButton = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
NewButton.click();
String Tooltip = NewButton.getText();
/*String Tooltip = NewButton.getAttribute("title"); // used this getattribute method also */
System.out.println(Tooltip);
```

I have used other methods also  similar like this method but not working Properly & not showing any errors in console also.

Please find below methods also:

```
//2nd method

/*Actions ActionChains = new Actions(wd);
WebElement NewButton = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
ActionChains.clickAndHold(NewButton).build().perform();
System.out.println("hold");
String Tooltip = NewButton.getText();
String Tooltip = NewButton.getAttribute("title");
System.out.println("done");
System.out.println(Tooltip);*/

//3rd method

/*String tooltip=wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(tooltip);
System.out.println("Done");*/

//4th method

/*WebElement ToolTip = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
System.out.println(ToolTip.getText());
System.out.println("Done");*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that tooltip which will be visible next to the Password field, you have to get that WebElement instead of the Password field. That field hasn't got title attribute, or text value. You can find the tooltip in the DOM if you search for:

```
<div class="jfk-bubble">...</div>
```

Code:

```
this.driver.get("copy your link here");
WebElement passwordField = this.driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd");
passwordField.click();

// Example: get the title of the tooltip
WebElement tooltipTitle = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p/strong"));

System.out.println("The title is: " + tooltipTitle.getText());
```

Return:

```
The title is: Password strength:
```

This tooltip is not in the DOM at the  beginning so you must set the WebElement only after click and use maybe WebDriverWait to avoid problems because of slow net connection, etc...